# How can I change one class in gwt-servlet.jar

Tags: gwt, jar

I just want to change one class file in gwt-servlet.jar. I already changed the source, compiled it and made a jar. But when I'm using it Eclipse claims that the type hierarchy is inconsistent.
How am I supposed to do with it?

UPDATE: Thanks Guys for trying to help, but I don´t have to change the class anymore, the Problem was something different...

Comment: What class do you want to change? no way to just override the class?

Comment: It would be quite interesting to review if you can share what file you changed.

Answer (score 0):

This error will also be displayed if your *`imports are out of sync`*, perhaps caused by a `re-build` using an external builder like `Ant`.

**FIX:**

To remedy this, hit 'Refresh' (F5) on your Project in Eclipse's Package Explorer.

*For more info check this* [link](http://java.syntaxerrors.info/index.php?title=Inconsistent_hierarchy)

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, but it is not due to this, i already did a lot of research on this.

Comment: Paste the code .How it is previous and what you changed .any stack trace ?

Comment: No stack trace, and the code is alright. For a quick solution i just put the changed .java-File in my src-folder, so that i can modify it and use it for now. But when i´m done with modifying, i want to put my modified java-file (and of course the .class file) back into gwt-servlet.java

Comment: While doing that please consider the package structure also .

Comment: It works just fine when i´m doing as described above, but not wehn i´m building a .jar...

Comment: After you modified java file in the src folder clean the project so new class file generate for that file you can find that class file in eclipse navigator .and then open the servlet jar and find the old one replace with new class file.

Answer (score 0):

You might get this error if you've added a reference to a non-existent interface or class in your patched version of the GWT class.

Comment: before i edited the .jar-file, it worked, no inconsistencies, but after editing and making a .jar again, it has these inconsistencies, even though the inherited .class is in the .jar-file